# The file “MyApp” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions, ios-simulator

To start off yes I know that this question is among many others on this site, but it seems that none of the other answers are working for me. Here is what has happened...

I originally had the Xcode file in its own folder in my documents, then I moved it onto an external hard drive, along with all my other files, and then wiped my hard drive. I can build the app but not run it on the simulator on on my device, and the last thing the little status bar at the top says is "signing product" So... just looking at other responses could this be because of me not having the "original" files? Thank you in advance for any help!

Oh a side note, I have the app on the app store, before it all went in the toilet, I don't know if that helps in any way. I have tried everything under the sun from changing the bundle identifier, getting new certificates, repairing permissions with disk utility, and clicking "ignore user permissions" on my external drive.

Answer (score 2):

select info

Enter Bundle name As : ${PRODUCT_NAME}

Executable file : ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}